# How to use SQL distinct on multi-pal columns

Tags: mysql, distinct

Below image shows the database table records, what I needed is to have distinct record depending on trno. column I tried this query,

```
SELECT distinct
    trno,
    srno,
    DATE_FORMAT(branch_transfer.date,'%d/%m/%Y')as transferdate,
    branch_transfer.product_code,
    product_master.product_name,
    product_master.product_desc,
    qty,
    branch_code,
    company_master.company_name,
    batch_code
    FROM
    branch_transfer INNER JOIN company_master
    ON 
    branch_transfer.branch_code = company_master.company_id
    INNER JOIN product_master
    ON
    branch_transfer.product_code=product_master.product_code
    where 
    branch_transfer.dstatus=1 and qty>0
    order by trno desc
```

[image]

but this query does not work as I thought, how to apply the distinct on multi-pal column. or how should I achieve this? I need distinct values depending on trno.

Answer (score 0):

Distinct removes duplicates from the Select list. So you will only see distinct trno values if all:

```
trno,
srno,
DATE_FORMAT(branch_transfer.date,'%d/%m/%Y')as transferdate,
branch_transfer.product_code,
product_master.product_name,
product_master.product_desc,
qty,
branch_code,
company_master.company_name,
batch_code
```

are the same...

I suspect you want to Group your data by trno. The question is then back to you. How do you want to deal with values where trno is duplicated? i.e. you want to take the largest one? perhaps sum them?

Comment: what i needed is to just have the single value from the table with unique trno

Comment: when you say "the single value" which of the columns do you mean?

Comment: Please can you add in your question an example of the results you want to see?